# Remove punctuation and number from string convert what's to what s and lik?e to like at the same time?

Tags: python, string, python-re

I'm trying to remove all punctuation and numbers in strings, and I saw this example online:

```
import re

a_string = '!hi. wh?at is the weat[h]er lik?e.'
new_string = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', a_string)
print(new_string)
hi what is the weather like
```

If I change the string like `"what's May 5th weat[h]er lik?e."`

How can I convert what's to what s; remove 5th; weat[h]er lik?e to weather like, at the same time? 5th is treated as a number.

So the new string would be like `"hi what s May weather like"`.

Comment: What is the criterion for `5th` case? Any *word* that has numbers?

Comment: I am thinking to treat it as a number. I want to remove all numbers and anything has a number.

Answer (score 2):

The provided script performs the following:

1. Replaces the single quotes to spaces.
2. Removes the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc...
3. Removes other punctuation.
4. Replaces multiple white-spaces with single spaces.

You can skip any step by commenting it.

```
import re

originalString = "!hi. what's May 5th weat[h]er lik?e."

# To replace the single quotes to spaces
newString = re.sub("'", ' ', originalString)
print(newString)  # Output: !hi. what s May 5th weat[h]er lik?e.

# To remove the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc...
newString = re.sub(r'[\d]+(st|nd|th)', '', newString)
print(newString)  # Output: !hi. what s May  weat[h]er lik?e.

# To remove other punctuation.
newString = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', newString)
print(newString)  # Output: hi what s May  weather like

# To replace multiple white-spaces with single spaces.
newString = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', newString)
print(newString)  # Output: hi what s May weather like
```